# null space of $T-\lambda I$ is finite dimensional using Riesz' lemma

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $T:X\to X$ be a compact linear
>   operator on a normed space $X$. Using Riesz's lemma prove that for every $\lambda\neq 0$, the
>   null space $\mathcal{N}(T_\lambda)$ of $T_\lambda=T-\lambda I$ is
>   finite dimensional.

Riesz's lemma states that : If $X$ be a normed space and $Y,Z\subseteq X$ such that $Y$ is a proper, closed subset of $Z$, then there exists a $z\in Z$ such that $||z||=1$ and for every $\theta\in(0,1)$ we have $||z-y||\geq\theta$ for all $y\in Y$.

Let's suppose the contrary that $\mathcal{N}(T_\lambda)$ is not finite-dimensional. Then $\mathcal{N}$ has a infinite linearly independent subset $(x_n)$. Now let $K_m=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m\}$. Now using that, if we can define a sequence which has no convergent subsequence, then compactness of $T$ is violated and we get a contradiction. But I can't get how to use Riesz's lemma on $K_m$ to define such a sequence. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that using the Riesz lemma we prove the noncompactness of a ball in infinite-dimensional space?

Comment: Hm, in fact if $X$ is infinite dimensional, we have the closed unit ball is noncompact. But what to do from there?

Comment: You have condition $Tx=\lambda x$. Assume that $\ker T_\lambda$ is infinite-dimensional and act on the unit ball of $\ker T_\lambda$ with the operator $T$.